# Append dynamic multiple lines header in to an .txt file which as data from data bricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-community-edition, databricks-cli, spark-bash-azure-databricks

I am trying to load data in to a abc.txt file form an .csv file which is stored in delta lake.

Example : Data load with | separation in abc.txt file

```
id|name|address|contact_no
1|abc|xyz1|123
2|efg|xyz2|456
3|hij|xyz3|789
4|klmn|xyz4|91011
```

Header data Example:

```
Table_Name|Employee_details
Execution Date|28.07.2021
Execution Time|13:30:06
Execution Date Range|01.01.2021 To 28.07.2021
Total Number of Records Extracted|1 To 59 of 59
Key Fields: id
```

how can i append these two in to one .txt file by using azure data bricks pyspark, or python.
Could any one of you assist here.

**I need abc.txt file to be loaded as below format**

```
Table_Name|Employee_details
Execution_Date|28.07.2021
Execution_Time|13:30:06
Execution_Date_Range|01.01.2021 To 28.07.2021
Total_Number_of_Records_Extracted|1 To 59 of 59
Key_Fields|id
```

```
id|name|address|contact_no
1|abc|xyz1|123
2|efg|xyz2|456
3|hij|xyz3|789
4|klmn|xyz4|91011
```

I am able to generate two separate files, but not able to do these in one file.

Answer (score 0):

File1.txt

[image]

File2.txt

[image]

```
df1 = spark.read.text("/FileStore/tables/File1.txt")
df2 = spark.read.text("/FileStore/tables/File2.txt")
unioned = df1.union(df2)
unioned.repartition(1).write.text("File3.txt")
```

[image]

Output dataframe

[image]

Now you can save Output dataframe to text file using below code.

```
np.savetxt(r'data\File3.txt', df.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

With The Above Same Scenario - After merging I want to Read the final .txt File With Pipe Separator But It is Giving me all Text Into 1st Column Whereas the other columns are - How Should I use the proper pipe separator for the same.
I Use Code :
df = spark.read.format("csv").options(header=True,sep = "|".schema(schema_fields).load(file_path)

Example :

```
pqr|abc|jkl|rst|xyz     Null    Null    Null
```

I wanted Output when we Read as:

```
abc                     a       b       c     d      e
pqr|abc|jkl|rst|xyz     pqr    abc     jkl    rst    xyz
```

#apacheSpark